# How to get an Owin UserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I want to ask Owin if a user exists.  Putting together random stuff I've found online, I end up with this (totally untested code):

```
/// <summary> Returns true if the TestUser user exists in the membership database. </summary>
public static bool UserExists(ApplicationDbContext db, string username)
{
    var userManager = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
        new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

    var user = userManager.FindByName(username);
    return (user != null);
}
```

My question is, do I really need that long, ugly expression to get a new UserManager?  Or is there a better, more efficient, cleaner, or more correct way to do this?

And now that I look a little more closely at it, I see that both UserManager and UserStore are disposable.  Do I want to wrap things in `using` blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as creating most any object, but in this case I would add some using statements to simplify it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Which would make your instantiation statement much tidier:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
```

Comment: But now that I look a little deeper, I see that the UserManager object has a Dispose method.  Should I wrap it in a `using` block?  And for that matter, UserStore is also disposable...

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do any of this and would instead use a DI framework.